# Convert a raw XML string into a list of java objects?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, xstream

Ok - I know this should be totally easy - but for some reason - I can't get it to work!

lets say I have the following POJO :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class PlainOldJavaObject implements Serializable {

    private long uuid;
    private String name;

    public PlainOldJavaObject() {
    }

    public long getUuid() {
        return this.uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(long uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getNamen() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /* Omitted HashCode & Equals for brevity. */
}
```

And lets say I have the following xml (I've formatted it for readabilty - really I get it as a raw, unformatted string) :

```
<PlainOldJavaObjects>
    <PlainOldJavaObject>
        <uuid>8119</uuid>
        <name>Jimmy</name>
    </PlainOldJavaObject>
    <PlainOldJavaObject>
        <uuid>2372</uuid>
        <name>Johns</name>
    </PlainOldJavaObject>
</PlainOldJavaObjects>
```

How in the living hell do I turn that XML into a List instance?

I tried using XStream - as follows :

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
List<PlainOldJavaObject> endResultHopefully = (List<PlainOldJavaObject>) xStream.fromXML(result);
```

But all that does is seemingly print the following to my terminal...

```
PlainOldJavaObjects : PlainOldJavaObjects
```

What the hell am I doing wrong here?

NOTE : ADDING JAXB TAG BECAUSE FROM GOOGLING THIS - I SEE THAT THIS EXISTS, AND I WOULD ASSUME IT MIGHT BE WHAT I WANT - BUT I AM NOT SURE, MAYBE SOMEONE OVER IN THAT COMMUNITY MIGHT HAVE SOME GUIDANCE FOR ME ALSO?

Comment: Use jaxb. This is what it does.

Comment: I can't seem to find an example of using jaxb for a list, without writing a wrapper class which the list lives inside of. Which is not something I would be able to bring in change-wise to this project.

Comment: The jaxb model is to map each element (complex type actually) to a Java class, which is why your "PlainOldJavaObjects" element needs a class. In my opinion, the best way to use jaxb is to drive it off of the XSD and have all of your pojos be generated at compile time (with all necessary annotations). This is a lot less code to maintain and the code pattern is easy to get used to. Jaxb is definitely the way to go if you are using XML - not sure how to convince the "powers that be" of that... Good luck.

Comment: You would need a top-level wrapper class `PlainOldJavaObjects` for holding the collection of objects in any case, not only when using JAXB, but also when using XStream.

Answer (score 0):

Use XStream and wrap your class in a PlainOldJavaObjects class containing a list of PlainOldJavaObject using @XStreamImplicit.
Here is an example. First, add an annotation to your PlainOldJavaObject class

```
@XStreamAlias("PlainOldJavaObject")
public class PlainOldJavaObject implements Serializable
{

    private long uuid;
    private String name;


    public PlainOldJavaObject()
    {
    }


    public long getUuid()
    {
        return this.uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(long uuid)
    {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getNamen()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Add @XStreamImplicit to the list of PlainOldJavaObject

```
@XStreamAlias("PlainOldJavaObjects")
public class PlainOldJavaObjects
{

    @XStreamImplicit
   private List<PlainOldJavaObject> pojoList = new 
ArrayList<PlainOldJavaObject>();

    public void addPojo(final PlainOldJavaObject pojo)
    {
        pojoList.add(pojo);
    }

    public List<PlainOldJavaObject> getList()
    {
        return pojoList;
    }
}
```

Class to test the result. First write out the resulting xml to a string. Then use the String to create the list you need.

```
public class TestXML
{

    @Test
    public void testXML()
    {
        PlainOldJavaObjects pojos = new PlainOldJavaObjects();

        PlainOldJavaObject pojo = new PlainOldJavaObject();

        pojo.setName("Jimmy");
        pojo.setUuid(8119);

        pojos.addPojo(pojo);

        PlainOldJavaObject pojo2 = new PlainOldJavaObject();
        pojo2.setName("Johns");
        pojo2.setUuid(2372);

        pojos.addPojo(pojo2);

        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.processAnnotations(PlainOldJavaObjects.class);
        xstream.processAnnotations(PlainOldJavaObject.class);

        String xml = xstream.toXML(pojos);
        System.out.println(xml);

        PlainOldJavaObjects pojos2 = (PlainOldJavaObjects) 
 xstream.fromXML(xml);

        // list with two PlainOldJavaObject
        assertEquals(2, pojos2.getList().size());
    }
}
```

Output from xml:

```
<PlainOldJavaObjects>
  <PlainOldJavaObject>
    <uuid>8119</uuid>
    <name>Jimmy</name>
  </PlainOldJavaObject>
  <PlainOldJavaObject>
    <uuid>2372</uuid>
    <name>Johns</name>
  </PlainOldJavaObject>
</PlainOldJavaObjects>
```